# Intermittent/transient errors on Azure Service bus topic

Tags: denial-of-service, bus

What are some good ways where we can proactively detect and retry service bus messages on getting intermittent/transient errors. An example of such an error we recieve is:

*The service was unable to process the request; please retry the operation. For more information on exception types and proper exception handling, please refer to http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=761101 Reference:0f965ca5-dd44-41f2-9f6a-19ffa9db6732, TrackingId:93635f0f0000025902753bf26017b9ba_G7_B36, SystemTracker:SB ClusterName:Topic:Topic-Name, Timestamp:2021-02-01T21:55:29*

Internally we are retrying the flow every 15 mins which also results in failures for a good amount of time (approx 2-3 hours). What are the best practices to then handle such intermittent failures so that our services don't suffer from it